# Can you add custom functions under Http Resource collection aside from toArray($request) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Http/Resources is a collection of modified properties come from the table column, however I found that I only found `toArray()` function inside the resources file. My question is can we add another method? and if yes, how can we use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Step 1. In your composer json inside autoload object add a helper file.

```
"autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

Here is the file

```
 "files": [
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ],
```

- Step 2. Create a folder Helpers inside app folder. then create a file helpers.php. here you can create your own function.

```php
<?php

if (! function_exists('dx')) {
    function dx($key, $default = null) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($key->toArray());
        die;
    }
}
```

- Step 3. finally run

```php
composer dump-autoload
```

- Now in controller you can use

```php
 $users = User::get();
 dx($users);
```